# Como fazer um pc entrar em sleep depois de falha de energia

Tags: windows, automatização

A minha questão é a seguinte, quero que o meu PC (windows 10) depois de uma falha de energia volte a ligar automaticamente mas... se eu não estiver a usar o PC na altura quero que ele entre em modo de sleep.

Na minha cabeça é fácil:

1- verificar se o pc veio de um estado de desligado
2- esperar 3 min e verificar se alguém fez logon
3- caso isso não aconteça colocar o pc em sleep mode

algum conselho como fazer isto?

Obrigado

Comment: O site é apenas sobre [desenvolvimento de software](/help/on-topic)